# Confusion about git pull --rebase

Tags: git, rebase

According to a tutorial I found : https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing/git-pull

git pull --rebase appends commits to your local tree.

```
    A - B - C (origin/master)
  /
D - E - F - G (local master)
```

After git pull --rebase on local the tutorial calims it should look like:

```
    A - B - C (origin/master)
  /
D - E - F - G - A - B - C (local master)
```

I would expect it to be like so :

```
  A - B - C (origin/master)
 /
D - A - B - C - E' - F' - G' (local master)
```

Am I missing something? or maybe they are wrong?

Comment: Hmm, looks like that page show a graph for `rebase` instead of `pull --rebase` indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.

That page is wrong, not only the graph, but also the text accompanying it:

> In this diagram, we can now see that a rebase pull does not create the new H commit. Instead, the rebase has copied the remote commits A--B--C and appended them to the local origin/master commit history.

The manual page is more clear:

> -r, --rebase[=false|true|preserve|interactive]
>
> ```
> When true, rebase the current branch on top of the upstream branch after
> fetching. If there is a remote-tracking branch corresponding to the
> upstream branch and the upstream branch was rebased since last fetched,
> the rebase uses that information to avoid rebasing non-local changes.
> ```

Comment: Thanks! Can you recommend a better tutorial? (or maybe it's a good one, just a minro glitch)

Comment: I'd recommend ProGit (https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) and Ultimate Beginner Git Cheatsheet (https://mukulrathi.com/git-beginner-cheatsheet/)

Answer (score 1):

If you have this.

```
    A - B - C (origin/master)
  /
D - E - F - G (master)
```

After `git pull --rebase`, assuming no new commits are fetched, you will have this.

```
D - A - B - C [origin/master]
             \
              E' - F' - G' [master]
```

E, F, and G are replayed on top of `origin/master`.

Note there's only one A, B, and C. Remotes and local branches all share the same commit tree.